# T4 Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'TypeMapper' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4

I've lost couple of days googling and trying to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>

<#@ assembly name="System.Text.RegularExpressions"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>

<#@ output extension=".txt" #>

Edmx fixer template
Started at: <#= DateTime.Now #>
<#  

    const string inputFile = @"DataModel.edmx";
    var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
    var edmx = XElement.Load(textTransform.Host.ResolvePath(inputFile), LoadOptions.SetBaseUri | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
    var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
    MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
   var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
    var itemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
  var coll = itemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>();
   var navigationProperties = typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection).SelectMany(item => typeMapper.GetNavigationProperties(item));
     Fix(navigationProperties, edmx);
    edmx.Save(textTransform.Host.ResolvePath(inputFile));
#>
```

(I have implemented Fix method, just didn't copy here because it's not necessary).

The error I've got all the time is that TypeMapper doesn't exist. I included EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude and try many other things, but the error appears all the time.
Does anyone have the same issue?

P.S. I'm using EF 6.1.3. and DB first approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue?